# JQuery: How to add a class to certain lines in textarea and display the modified textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So what I am trying to do is:

-> Get contents from textarea (input by user) (var entered).

-> Split each line by \n and store them in a variable (var lines).

-> Use a for loop to iterate through all lines and add class (.modify) to the lines that does not contain characters `[\u3400-\u9FBF]`. Other lines stays the same.

-> Store all lines in a new container (div class="new_text) and display it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<!--DOCTYPE html-->
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            textarea { 
              width: 650px; 
              min-width:650px; 
              max-width:650px; 
              height:650px; 
              min-height:650px;  
              max-height:650px;
            }
            .modify {
              color : red;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() { 
                $("#test").click(function(){
                    var i; 
                    var entered = $('#textInput').val();
                    var lines = entered.split('\n');
                    res = "";
                    for(i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
                        if (lines[i].match(/[\u3400-\u9FBF]/)) {
                            res = lines[i];
                            $(".new_text").append(res);
                        } else {
                            res = lines[i];
                            $(".new_text").append(res).addClass("modify");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="userInput">
                    <label for="textInput">Input Here:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="40" id="textInput"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-Warning" id="test">Test</button>
            </form>
            <div class="new_text"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This however does not change anything from the original textarea input, any idea what is wrong? or is this not an acceptable way to accomplish what I am trying to do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have the click event binded to the element with id="test" . no such element exist in your example.

Comment: yes sorry its a button i forgot to add it here, will change the code

Comment: what does regex [\u3400-\u9FBF] represent ?

Comment: they are chinese/japanese characters I believ, and I'm trying to keep those characters the same

Comment: I added details regarding your "everything is red" comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the item which doesn't contain the required condition, you need to wrap the text inside an element in order to apply a css class.

```
for(i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
            if (lines[i].match(/[\u3400-\u9FBF]/))
            {
              res = lines[i];
              $(".new_text").append(res);
            }
            else
            {
                res = lines[i];
                $('<p/>',{
                  text: res,
                  'class': 'modify'
              }).appendTo('.new_text');             
            }
          }
```

Here's the working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6x80vabm/10/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with all the text going red is because you're adding the "modify" class to ".new_text" and not to your new element.

You need to call `append` with valid HTML.  A line of text won't be sufficient.  Try this:

`$(".new_text").append(
  $("<p>" + res + "</p>").addClass("modify")
);`

Comment: This answer is correct, however - if you want to display the markup as text in a textfield, I am almost positive you need to escape any selectors before appending. Otherwise it will be treated as a DOM element and screw up the rest of your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Ditto to the first answer. You can only add a class to proper HTML.

Also, inside of the modify selector, you have `color = red;`. That's invalid CSS. It should be `color: red;`.

Another problem I noticed is that there is no button with `id="test"`, so there's nothing that will actually trigger the test click handler.

Comment: thank you, I have updated the code, but the problem now is that the entire text is red but I only want lines in the 'else' statement to change.